# Open all Google Docs in view mode by default regardless of each doc's settings?

Tags: google-docs, google-workspace-for-business

Is there a way to set my Google [Workspace] account so that any time I open a link someone has sent me to a Google Doc (or Sheet, Slides, etc.), it always opens in View mode, regardless of the document's settings?

When I'm first reading someone else's document, I don't want accidental key presses to act as an edit or suggestion. So I want to always open all documents— regardless of who created them or how the owner set that doc's settings, or what kind of sharing link they used to share it—in View mode by default, so that I have to intentionally switch to Suggest or Edit mode if I want to suggest or make changes.

Comment: Seems like it can't be done without changing permissions or creating a restricted sharing link: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/10477369/how-to-open-google-doc-always-in-viewing-mode?hl=en